# React rendering invisible components when using enum for conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have a React component that needs to conditionally render one of two other components, like so:

```
render() {
  const displayMode = this.props.condition ? 'a' : 'b';

  return (
     <div>
        {{
           a: <AComponent />,
           b: <BComponent userData={this.props.userData} />
        }[displayMode]}
     </div>
  );
}
...
```

BComponent requires data that AComponent doesn't, and so that data isn't available when AComponent is rendering. The unexpected behavior is that even when only AComponent should be rendering, I'm getting errors about missing data required only for BComponent.

In short, both components are always rendering when I use the object enum.

If I switch it up to the following:

```
render() {
  const displayMode = this.props.condition ? 'a' : 'b';

  return (
     <div>
        {displayMode === 'a' && (
           <AComponent />
        )}

        {displayMode === 'b' && (
           <BComponent />
        )}
     </div>
  );
}
...
```

Then I don't have this problem, only the expected component is being rendered and I don't received any errors regarding data required for the other component.

So, this works, but I prefer the cleaner code using the object enum. My question is why the odd behavior, and is this expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between 2 solutions is the execution order. In the first case, a new object with 2 keys a & b is created, along with corresponding components `AComponent` and `BComponent`, then taken out value of key matching `displayMode`. In the second case, `displayMode` is verified first, and based on its value, the second condition will or will not be taken. It is similar to executing: `!!undefined && undefined.raiseNoError` - the second condition is ignored since it doesn't pass the first condition.

Comment: That actually seems almost obvious now; well done. Thanks!